# Show that $f(x,y) = x(y^{2}+x-2)$ is continuous at the point $(1,0)$ - Help with the last bit of algebra

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, continuity

I know what it is I'm supposed to be doing, but I'm having trouble arriving at a value for my $\delta$.

The question states: Compute the following limits if they exist and if they do, prove it. Specifically for this question the function is: $f(x,y) = x(y^{2}+x-2)$  at the point $(1,0)$. At this point $f(x,y) = -1$. As such I want to find a $\delta > 0$ such that

$$|f(x,y) - f(1,0)| < \epsilon\ \text{when}\ |(x,y) - (1,0)| = |(x-1,y - 0)| < \delta $$

After a little algebra I've arrived at the following expression:

$$|x^{2} +x(y^{2}-2)+1| < \epsilon$$

I had thought about completing the square with respect to $x$ being the variable, but that appears to be messy and doesn't lead me anywhere. Suggestions on how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|x^2+x(y^2-2)+1|=|x^2-2x+1+x(y^2-2)+2x| \leq |x-1|^2+|x|y^2$

Comment: Simply adding $0$ was the way through.....thanks for the assistance.